# Looping through a set of buttons

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I've written a small script that loops through a set of buttons each of which is assigned a function. Script is below:

```
$('#play').bind('click', function() {
    setTimeout( function(){ $('#b12').click(); }, 0 );
    setTimeout( function(){ $('#b13').click(); }, 2500 );
    setTimeout( function(){ $('#b14').click(); }, 5000 );
});
```

Now this works fine but I'm trying to make it a little more automated than just calling each function with the `setTimeout'. I've got the code below but I think I'm doing something wrong:

```
$('#play').click(function(){ 
    $('.buttons').each(function(){
        var time = 0;
        setTimeout( function(){ $(this).click(); }, time );
        time+= 2500;
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML in question:

```
<button id="b12" class="buttons" onclick="oct12()">12th</button>
<button id="b13" class="buttons" onclick="oct13()">13th</button>
<button id="b14" class="buttons" onclick="oct14()">14th</button>

<button id="play">play</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the index of .each for this, in ur own code u resetted time every iteration

```
   $('#play').click(function(){
       $('.buttons').each(function(i){
        setTimeout( function(){ $(this).click(); }, i * 2500);                
       });

  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/me2nR/4/)

Comment: Maybe you can explain, what you're trying to reach, because I was only making your code more flexible. You've a click event on each of the buttons now, but what do you like to ouput

Comment: what I'm trying to do is; make the function behind each button run when the play button is clicked, with an interval between each one. The first bit of code I've got works fine, but I wanted to make it a little "better" (for want of a better word). In other words, is there a better way for me to do the first bit of script I put....

Comment: I bit of ur comment fell off, I think it's not aloud to make large comments, but if I understand u well: You like to have click events on all of the buttons, but the user can only click if the time u've set is passed. So u want to disable the buttons if the interval isn't passed?

Comment: no basically what I'm trying to do is create a function with a time delay that runs all of the functions `oct12, oct13, oct14` and bind it to the "play" button.

Answer (score 1):

put you `time` variable outside .each() like code bellow:

```
$('#play').click(function(){ 
    var time = 0;
    $('.buttons').each(
        setTimeout( function(){ $(this).click(); }, time );
        time+= 2500;
    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work. But my initial mistake of resetting time was so silly!

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like the [plugin jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/). This makes timing issues very easy:

```
$('#play').bind('click').$('#b12,#b13,#b14').each($).click().wait(2500);
```

That's it.

This example uses the plugin's [inline version of bind()](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/handler/.bind_timed.html), the [sequentially looped version of each()](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/each/.each_sequential.html), and the deferring method [wait(timeout)](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/wait/.wait_timeout.html).

PS: I like to write .on('click') instead of .bind('click') because it reads more fluently like a sentence.